# data binding is not working on multiple form controls while opening a form in edit mode

Tags: angular, typescript

on clicking on edit button it is loading data on the form using [(ng-model)], which is working fine on few fields but no on all fields. It is displaying data only in few fields while receiving data in all fields here is the html code of the form in which i am implementing ngmodel.

```
          <form  id="cardForm{{i+1}}">
        <div class="row row-custom mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Account Nickname" [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i].name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
                <div class="font-red" *ngIf="(f.name.touched || f.name.dirty)  && f.name.errors">
                  {{getValidationErrors(f.name.errors)}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Card Name"
                    [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i].other.cardName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
                <div class="font-red" *ngIf="(f.cardName.touched || f.cardName.dirty)  && f.cardName.errors">
                  {{getValidationErrors(f.cardName.errors)}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Credit/Debit Card Number
                " id="cardno" autocomplete="off" maxlength="19" [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i]?.other.cardNumber" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" credit-card
                       (input)="validatecardnumber($event)">
                <div class="font-red"
                     *ngIf="(f.cardNumber.touched || f.cardNumber.dirty) && f.cardNumber.errors &&  !myForm.get('cardNumber').hasError('invalidNumber')">
                  {{getValidationErrors(f.cardNumber.errors)}}
                </div>
                <div class="font-red" *ngIf="(f.cardNumber.touched || f.cardNumber.dirty)  && myForm.get('cardNumber').hasError('invalidNumber')">
                  Please enter a valid card number.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input matInput class="form-control" #pickerInput maxlength="7" appInputMask autocomplete="off"
                       [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Expiration Date MM-YYYY" [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i]?.other.expirationDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                       [min]="minDate">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #dp startView="multi-year" (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
                                (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)" panelClass="example-month-picker">
                </mat-datepicker>
                <div class="font-red"
                     *ngIf="(f.expirationDate.touched || f.expirationDate.dirty) && f.expirationDate?.invalid ">
                  {{getExpirationDateErrorMessage(pickerInput.value)}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Street
      " id="street" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i]?.other.street" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">-->
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Street
        " id="city" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i]?.other.street" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                <div class="font-red" *ngIf="(f.street.touched || f.street.dirty) && f.street.errors">
                  {{getValidationErrors(f.street.errors)}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row row-custom">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City
        " id="city" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50"  [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i]?.other.city" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                    <div class="font-red" *ngIf="(f.city.touched || f.city.dirty) && f.city.errors">
                      {{getValidationErrors(f.city.errors)}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="selectbox">
                      <select class="form-select form-control select-width" [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i]?.other.state" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                        <option [ngValue]="null">State</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let st of stateList" [value]="st.name">{{st.name}}</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="font-red" *ngIf="(f.state.touched || f.state.dirty) && f.state.errors">
                      {{getValidationErrors(f.state.errors)}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ZipCode" [(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i]?.other.zipCode" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                           id="zipCode" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10"  
                           (keyup)="validateZipCode($event)" >
                    <div class="font-red" *ngIf="(f.zipCode.touched || f.zipCode.dirty) && f.zipCode.errors">
                      {{getValidationErrors(f.zipCode.errors)}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

on the ts file side i am calling a method editCardById(card?.id,i) on the click of edit button which is taking card.id and index value to displaying a form

```
 getCardById(cardId,index) {
this._transactionService.getCardById(cardId).subscribe((response) => {
  if (!this._commonService.isEmptyObject(response)) {
    this.cardByIds[index].other = new Other();
     this.cardByIds[index].maskedCardNumber = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.maskedCardNumber);
     this.cardByIds[index].expirationMonth = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.expirationMonth);
     this.cardByIds[index].expirationYear = this._commonService.decrypt(response?.expirationYear);
    this.cardByIds[index].fourDigit = this.cardByIds[index].maskedCardNumber.slice(this.cardByIds[index].maskedCardNumber.length - 4);
     this.cardByIds[index].default = response?.default;
     this.cardByIds[index].id = response?.id;
     this.cardByIds[index].name = response?.name;
    this.cardByIds[index].type = response?.type;
    this.cardByIds[index].other.nameOnCard = (response.other.nameOnCard != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.nameOnCard) : '';
     this.cardByIds[index].other.address1 = (response.other.address1 != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.address1) : '';
     this.cardByIds[index].other.address2 = (response.other.address2 != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.address2) : '';
     this.cardByIds[index].other.city = (response.other.city != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.city) : '';
     this.cardByIds[index].other.country = (response.other.country != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.country) : '';
     this.cardByIds[index].other.number = (response.other.number != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.number) : '';
    this.cardByIds[index].other.state = (response.other.state != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.state) : '';
    this.cardByIds[index].other.zipcode = (response.other.zipcode != '') ? this._commonService.decrypt(response?.other.zipcode) : '';
    this.cardByIds[index].showData = true;
  }
```

adding a screenshot of UI on which it is displaying the value received from api but not able to bind with ng model
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you're not setting all values in your `getCardById` callback.

For instance, you have this binding on the Card Name input:

`[(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i].other.cardName"`

but I can't see where you're setting that value (you're setting `this.cardByIds[index].other.nameOnCard`, instead).

Same for `[(ngModel)]="cardByIds[i]?.other.street"`. Double check your callback and be sure to set all the values you want to display.